# not able to install pandas-profiling in python 3.11 anaconda navigator

Tags: pandas-profiling

This is the error given by anaconda jupyter notebook
ERROR: ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. gensim 4.3.0 requires Fuzz

I tried installing with pip install ydata-profiling
also with pip install pandas-profiling